# Android, file transferring

Tags: android

How does one transfer a file (p2p prefered, if possible) between two android phones?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Qualcomm's free peer-to-peer SDK

http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/alljoyn-p2p